# How to use db instead of Laravel localization config file

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-localization

I'm using **mcamara/laravel-localization**. I need to get languages from db instead of **laravellocalization** config file. Any ideas how to do that. I would be so grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to use the laravel translation loader:

Install Laravel translation loader through Composer:

```
composer require spatie/laravel-translation-loader
```

Then publish Laravel translation loader migration file:

```
 php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\TranslationLoader\TranslationServiceProvider" --tag="migrations"
```

Finally, run the migrations; it will create a new table called language_lines in the database:

```
php artisan migrate
```

UPDATE: for laravel 6+ see the Issue @ [github](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/issues/1567)

source: [Laravel news](https://laravel-news.com/translation-loader-package)

Comment: I tried to install, but got and error `  Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class name must be a valid object or a string
`

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using laravel 6.2

Comment: try running composer dump-autoload...The issue is with laravel 6 here is the issue: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/issues/1567

Comment: Ok, that works. Now I have an empty table. What's next.

Comment: Nice to hear it works see the link: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translation-loader